# Help with the application of the infinite geometric series rule.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We have that

$$p=\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{d}{(1+r)^t}$$

Where *d* is a constant and *r* is a percentage. I am trying to deduce the result $d/r$ by the rule of infinite geometric series that states when *a* is constant and $|x|<1$,

$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \ ax^t=\frac{a}{1-x}$$

The closest I get by substitutions is to $-d/r$. I would be very grateful if someone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may write, by a change of index, using the geometric sum evaluation,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{d}{(1+r)^t}&= \frac{d}{(1+r)}\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+r)^{t-1}}
\\\\&= \frac{d}{(1+r)}\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+r)^{t}}
\\\\&=\frac{d}{(1+r)} \cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{(1+r)}}
\\\\&=\frac{d}{(1+r)-1}
\\\\&=\frac dr.
\end{align}
$$